# Reflect in terraform state existing CloudSQL instance

Tags: terraform, google-cloud-sql

I've created CloudSQL instances manually and now I need to manage them via terraform.
I've described them in instance.tf file and tried to apply but got an error:

*Error, failed to create  googleapi: Error 409: The Cloud SQL instance already exists., instanceAlreadyExists*

I've tried to do terraform refresh, but since this instance not in terraform state file yet - it can't be reflected.

How to reflect existing infrastructure in state file?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Terraform CLI import command. This will associate the existing instance with the resource in your Terraform files.

The exact invocation will depend on your configuration.

```
terraform import your_resource.name_in_terraform gcp-instance-name
```

This a useful (albeit AWS focused) [article](https://spacelift.io/blog/importing-exisiting-infrastructure-into-terraform).

---

**Update**: Once you've successfully run `terraform import` you should run `terraform plan` and see what the differences are between your existing instance and what is in your terraform configuration. If you just want to import what is there then the next step is to update your configuration so that it matches the difference shown in the plan output.

Answer (score 1):

Just to complement [machbutch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/141923/macbutch) answer, after you import the resource, run terraform plan to check the differences and add them to your terraform configuration before applying.

Terraform has many "invisible default values" that may be differ from the resource you created manually.

Comment: Yeah, this is a very good point. I've updated my answer to try to clarify that.